# Phonegap makes me confused

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, emulation

I've new to app development and I thought of trying Phonegap. I've already downloaded Node.js and git.client. I have 4 questions:
1) So, I'm installing the PhoneGap and as soon as I type the first line of code from : [image] into Terminal on my Mac, I keep getting asked a password. What password are they asking for and how do I type it in? Or do I just move on without a password?

2)Once I'm done with that, I move on to docs.phonegap.com and head to the Command Line Interface guide. I'm running the code on terminal and can't seem to run the platforms for android, blackberry10 and amazon fireos as said in: [image]
Does this mean I need to install other things in order to get the different platforms running?

3) Moving on and working on the ios platform, I'm suppose to test the app on a emulator or a device, just like this: [image]
All I did was change the "android" to "ios" in the code, but when I do that, it seems I need to download something from GitHub or Nodejs. What do I install?

4) When I'm at GitHub, a lot of the downloads are clones. Does this mean it is illegal?

As you can see, so stuck! Would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: When a `sudo` command prompts you for a password, enter your own password.

Comment: My computer password or a PhoneGap password? Or do I create my own password then because I don't have a PhoneGap password.

Comment: Your own password. [`sudo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) tells your computer to run the command you give it with elevated privileges (usually `root` on Linux machines, I'm not sure what the admin account on Macs is called). Your step 1. command *installs PhoneGap* using Node.js's package manager [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.org/).

Comment: Ahh I see. But as I'm trying that, no letters come out. Do I have to type the "command" key when I'm typing the password. Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: Nope, just type your password and press Enter. Nothing is shown on the screen by design.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sign up for their developer program and then enter that password

Comment: But there isn't a way to sign up for PhoneGap. You just start by installing it.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The password prompt is for `sudo`, not for PhoneGap. `sudo` prompts users for their own password.

Answer (score 0):

1.) It asking your PC login password, because you are installing a new SW.

2.) Yes, you must install many other SW for diferrent platforms. Cordova is only FW, not IDE...
Android need istall Eclipse, into it ADT plugin and android developer tools, and so on with the other platforms. Things you are need to know are in in docs for every platform.

How you can ask question No. 3 before you don't have answer on the first and the second question?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will definitely go through the docs for all the different platforms. One of my attempts, instead of adding the password, I just went on to the next step (which worked!). So, since the ios platform was working, I continued only on that, until the emulator part (question 4). Would you be able to answer question 4?

Comment: Well, probably only thing you downloaded from git (despite that it have many packages, which are downloaded separatedly) is Cordova FW. Cordova is developed by Apache foundation and licenses by Apacha 2.0 license. This is benevolent license – you can change Cordova code, you can use it in commercial sector, etc. For more info you can google it. In short, it is not illegal. Is it answer to your question?